# Complex string filtering with python

Tags: python, trim

I have a long string that is a phylogenetic tree and I want to do a very specific filtering.

```
(Esy@ESY15_g64743_DN3_SP7_c0:0.0726396855636,Aar@AA_maker7399_1:0.137507902808,((Spa@Tp2g18720:0.0318934795022,Cpl@CP2_g48793_DN3_SP8_c:0.0273465005242):9.05326020871e-05,(((Bst@Bostr_13083s0053_1:0.0332592496158,((Aly@AL8G21130_t1:0.0328569260951,Ath@AT5G48370_1:0.0391706378372):0.0205924636564,(Chi@CARHR183840_1:0.0954469923893,Cru@Carubv10026342m:0.0570981548016):0.00998579652059):0.0150356382287):0.0340484449097,(((Hco@scaff1034_g23864_DN3_SP8_c_TE35_CDS100:0.00823215335663,Hlo@DN13684_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0085462978729):0.0144626717872,Hla@DN22821_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0225079453622):0.0206478928557,Hse@DN23412_c0_g1_i3_p1:0.048590776459):0.0372829371381):0.00859075940423,(Esa@Thhalv10004228m:0.0378509854703,Aal@Aa_G102140_t1:0.0712272454125):1.00000050003e-06):0.00328120860999):0.0129090235079):0.0129090235079;
```

Basically every `x@y` is a `species@gene_id` information. What I am trying to do is trimming this down so that I will only have `x` instead of `x@y`.

```
(Esy, Aar,(Spa,Cpl))...
```

I tried splitting the string first but the problem is string has different 'split points' for what I want to achieve i.e. some parts `x@y` is ending with a `,` and others with a `)`. I searched for a solution and saw regular expression operations, but I am new to Python and I couldn't be sure if that is what I should be focusing on. I also thought about `strip()` but it seems like I need to specify the characters to be stripped for this.

Main problem is there is no 'pattern' for me to tell Python to follow. Only thing is that all species ids are 3 letters and they are before an `@` character.

Is there a method that can do what I want? I will be really glad if you can help me out with my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you need to come up with a more complex parsing algorithm. I suggest you do some reading about "tokenizing" and "parsing". My idea would be to parse the entire phylogenetic tree into what we call an Abstract Syntax Tree. Then you can navigate the tree and get the pieces that you want.

Comment: have you tried a regex match?  It would seem logical to simply match '...@'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this kind of function:

```
def parse_string(string):
    new_string = ''
    skip = False
    for char in string:
        if char == '@':
            skip = True
        if char == ',':
            skip = False
        if not skip or char in ['(', ')']:
            new_string += char
    return new_string
```

Calling it on your string:

```
string = '(Esy@ESY15_g64743_DN3_SP7_c0:0.0726396855636,Aar@AA_maker7399_1:0.137507902808,((Spa@Tp2g18720:0.0318934795022,Cpl@CP2_g48793_DN3_SP8_c:0.0273465005242):9.05326020871e-05,(((Bst@Bostr_13083s0053_1:0.0332592496158,((Aly@AL8G21130_t1:0.0328569260951,Ath@AT5G48370_1:0.0391706378372):0.0205924636564,(Chi@CARHR183840_1:0.0954469923893,Cru@Carubv10026342m:0.0570981548016):0.00998579652059):0.0150356382287):0.0340484449097,(((Hco@scaff1034_g23864_DN3_SP8_c_TE35_CDS100:0.00823215335663,Hlo@DN13684_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0085462978729):0.0144626717872,Hla@DN22821_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0225079453622):0.0206478928557,Hse@DN23412_c0_g1_i3_p1:0.048590776459):0.0372829371381):0.00859075940423,(Esa@Thhalv10004228m:0.0378509854703,Aal@Aa_G102140_t1:0.0712272454125):1.00000050003e-06):0.00328120860999):0.0129090235079):0.0129090235079;'
parse_string(string)
> '(Esy,Aar,((Spa,Cpl),(((Bst,((Aly,Ath),(Chi,Cru))),(((Hco,Hlo),Hla),Hse)),(Esa,Aal))))'
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
import re:

pat = re.compile(r'(\w{3})@')
txt = "(Esy@ESY15_g64743_DN3_SP7_c0:0.0726396855636,Aar@AA_maker7399_1:0.137507902808,((Spa@Tp2g18720:0.0318934795022,Cpl@CP2_g48793_DN3_SP8_c:0.0273465005242):9.05326020871e-05,(((Bst@Bostr_13083s0053_1:0.0332592496158,((Aly@AL8G21130_t1:0.0328569260951,Ath@AT5G48370_1:0.0391706378372):0.0205924636564,(Chi@CARHR183840_1:0.0954469923893,Cru@Carubv10026342m:0.0570981548016):0.00998579652059):0.0150356382287):0.0340484449097,(((Hco@scaff1034_g23864_DN3_SP8_c_TE35_CDS100:0.00823215335663,Hlo@DN13684_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0085462978729):0.0144626717872,Hla@DN22821_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0225079453622):0.0206478928557,Hse@DN23412_c0_g1_i3_p1:0.048590776459):0.0372829371381):0.00859075940423,(Esa@Thhalv10004228m:0.0378509854703,Aal@Aa_G102140_t1:0.0712272454125):1.00000050003e-06):0.00328120860999):0.0129090235079):0.0129090235079;"
pat.findall(t)
```

Result:

```
['Esy', 'Aar', 'Spa', 'Cpl', 'Bst', 'Aly', 'Ath', 'Chi', 'Cru', 'Hco', 'Hlo', 'Hla', 'Hse', 'Esa', 'Aal']
```

If you need the structure intact, we can try to remove the unnecessary parts instead:

```
pat = re.compile(r'(@|:)[^/),]*')
pat.sub('',t).replace(',', ', ')
```

Result:

```
'(Esy, Aar, ((Spa, Cpl), (((Bst, ((Aly, Ath), (Chi, Cru))), (((Hco, Hlo), Hla), Hse)), (Esa, Aal))))'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KGQfRl/1)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to parse a phylogenetic tree, I highly suggest to let BioPython do the heavy lifting for you.

You can easily parse and display a phylogenetic with [Bio.Phylo](https://biopython.org/wiki/Phylo). Then it is just iterating over all tree elements and splitting the names at the 'at'-sign.

Because Phylo expects the input to be in a file, we create an in-memory file-like object with `io.StringIO`. Getting the complete tree is then as easy as

`Phylo.read(io.StringIO(s), 'newick')`

In order to check if the parsed tree looks sane, I print it once with `print(tree)`.

Now we want to change all node names that contain a `'@'`. With `tree.find_elements` we get access to all nodes. Some nodes don't have a name and some might not contain a `'@'`. So to be extra careful, we first check `if n.name and '@' in n.name`. Only then do we split each node's name at the `'@'` and take just the first part (index 0) of it:
`n.name = n.name.split('@')[0]`

In order to recreate the initial string representation, we use `Phylo.write`:

```py
out = io.StringIO()
Phylo.write(tree, out, "newick")
print(out.getvalue())
```

Again, `write` wants to get a file argument - if we just want to get a string, we can use a `StringIO` object again.

**Full code:**

```py
import io

from Bio import Phylo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = '(Esy@ESY15_g64743_DN3_SP7_c0:0.0726396855636,Aar@AA_maker7399_1:0.137507902808,((Spa@Tp2g18720:0.0318934795022,Cpl@CP2_g48793_DN3_SP8_c:0.0273465005242):9.05326020871e-05,(((Bst@Bostr_13083s0053_1:0.0332592496158,((Aly@AL8G21130_t1:0.0328569260951,Ath@AT5G48370_1:0.0391706378372):0.0205924636564,(Chi@CARHR183840_1:0.0954469923893,Cru@Carubv10026342m:0.0570981548016):0.00998579652059):0.0150356382287):0.0340484449097,(((Hco@scaff1034_g23864_DN3_SP8_c_TE35_CDS100:0.00823215335663,Hlo@DN13684_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0085462978729):0.0144626717872,Hla@DN22821_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0225079453622):0.0206478928557,Hse@DN23412_c0_g1_i3_p1:0.048590776459):0.0372829371381):0.00859075940423,(Esa@Thhalv10004228m:0.0378509854703,Aal@Aa_G102140_t1:0.0712272454125):1.00000050003e-06):0.00328120860999):0.0129090235079):0.0129090235079;'

    tree = Phylo.read(io.StringIO(s), 'newick')
    print(' before '.center(20, '='))
    print(tree)

    for n in tree.find_elements():
        if n.name and '@' in n.name:
            n.name = n.name.split('@')[0]

    print(' result '.center(20, '='))
    out = io.StringIO()
    Phylo.write(tree, out, "newick")
    print(out.getvalue())
```

**Output:**

```
====== before ======
Tree(rooted=False, weight=1.0)
    Clade(branch_length=0.0129090235079)
        Clade(branch_length=0.0726396855636, name='Esy@ESY15_g64743_DN3_SP7_c0')
        Clade(branch_length=0.137507902808, name='Aar@AA_maker7399_1')
        Clade(branch_length=0.0129090235079)
            Clade(branch_length=9.05326020871e-05)
                Clade(branch_length=0.0318934795022, name='Spa@Tp2g18720')
                Clade(branch_length=0.0273465005242, name='Cpl@CP2_g48793_DN3_SP8_c')
            Clade(branch_length=0.00328120860999)
                Clade(branch_length=0.00859075940423)
                    Clade(branch_length=0.0340484449097)
                        Clade(branch_length=0.0332592496158, name='Bst@Bostr_13083s0053_1')
                        Clade(branch_length=0.0150356382287)
                            Clade(branch_length=0.0205924636564)
                                Clade(branch_length=0.0328569260951, name='Aly@AL8G21130_t1')
                                Clade(branch_length=0.0391706378372, name='Ath@AT5G48370_1')
                            Clade(branch_length=0.00998579652059)
                                Clade(branch_length=0.0954469923893, name='Chi@CARHR183840_1')
                                Clade(branch_length=0.0570981548016, name='Cru@Carubv10026342m')
                    Clade(branch_length=0.0372829371381)
                        Clade(branch_length=0.0206478928557)
                            Clade(branch_length=0.0144626717872)
                                Clade(branch_length=0.00823215335663, name='Hco@scaff1034_g23864_DN3_SP8_c_TE35_CDS100')
                                Clade(branch_length=0.0085462978729, name='Hlo@DN13684_c0_g1_i1_p1')
                            Clade(branch_length=0.0225079453622, name='Hla@DN22821_c0_g1_i1_p1')
                        Clade(branch_length=0.048590776459, name='Hse@DN23412_c0_g1_i3_p1')
                Clade(branch_length=1.00000050003e-06)
                    Clade(branch_length=0.0378509854703, name='Esa@Thhalv10004228m')
                    Clade(branch_length=0.0712272454125, name='Aal@Aa_G102140_t1')

==== result =====
(Esy:0.07264,Aar:0.13751,((Spa:0.03189,Cpl:0.02735):0.00009,(((Bst:0.03326,((Aly:0.03286,Ath:0.03917):0.02059,(Chi:0.09545,Cru:0.05710):0.00999):0.01504):0.03405,(((Hco:0.00823,Hlo:0.00855):0.01446,Hla:0.02251):0.02065,Hse:0.04859):0.03728):0.00859,(Esa:0.03785,Aal:0.07123):0.00000):0.00328):0.01291):0.01291;
```

The default format of Phylo uses less digits than in your original tree. In order to keep the numbers unchanged, just override the branch length format string with a '%s':

```py
Phylo.write(tree, out, "newick", format_branch_length="%s")
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the topic of phylogenetic at all, but I think your answer has the potential to be the right one.  If you could clarify in your answer how this gets exactly what OP wants (just the `name` and structure) I think it would be more helpful.  Right now your answer just look a bit too noisy.

Comment: This is definitely a more comprehensive answer. Although a simpler answer solved my problem, I will definitely look into Biopython for my further needs.

Comment: In case you will be working with such problems more often, I highly recommend it. Reinventing the wheel every time you are faced with a new problem does not scale well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex if you need the brackets in the output:

```
import re
regex = r"@[A-Za-z0-9_\.:]+|[0-9:\.;e-]+"
phylogenetic_tree = "(Esy@ESY15_g64743_DN3_SP7_c0:0.0726396855636,Aar@AA_maker7399_1:0.137507902808,((Spa@Tp2g18720:0.0318934795022,Cpl@CP2_g48793_DN3_SP8_c:0.0273465005242):9.05326020871e-05,(((Bst@Bostr_13083s0053_1:0.0332592496158,((Aly@AL8G21130_t1:0.0328569260951,Ath@AT5G48370_1:0.0391706378372):0.0205924636564,(Chi@CARHR183840_1:0.0954469923893,Cru@Carubv10026342m:0.0570981548016):0.00998579652059):0.0150356382287):0.0340484449097,(((Hco@scaff1034_g23864_DN3_SP8_c_TE35_CDS100:0.00823215335663,Hlo@DN13684_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0085462978729):0.0144626717872,Hla@DN22821_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0225079453622):0.0206478928557,Hse@DN23412_c0_g1_i3_p1:0.048590776459):0.0372829371381):0.00859075940423,(Esa@Thhalv10004228m:0.0378509854703,Aal@Aa_G102140_t1:0.0712272454125):1.00000050003e-06):0.00328120860999):0.0129090235079):0.0129090235079;"

print(re.sub(regex,"",phylogenetic_tree))
```

Output:

```
(Esy,Aar,((Spa,Cpl),(((Bst,((Aly,Ath),(Chi,Cru))),(((Hco,Hlo),Hla),Hs)),(Esa,Aal))))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex:

```
import re 
s = "(Esy@ESY15_g64743_DN3_SP7_c0:0.0726396855636,Aar@AA_maker7399_1:0.137507902808,((Spa@Tp2g18720:0.0318934795022,Cpl@CP2_g48793_DN3_SP8_c:0.0273465005242):9.05326020871e-05,(((Bst@Bostr_13083s0053_1:0.0332592496158,((Aly@AL8G21130_t1:0.0328569260951,Ath@AT5G48370_1:0.0391706378372):0.0205924636564,(Chi@CARHR183840_1:0.0954469923893,Cru@Carubv10026342m:0.0570981548016):0.00998579652059):0.0150356382287):0.0340484449097,(((Hco@scaff1034_g23864_DN3_SP8_c_TE35_CDS100:0.00823215335663,Hlo@DN13684_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0085462978729):0.0144626717872,Hla@DN22821_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0225079453622):0.0206478928557,Hse@DN23412_c0_g1_i3_p1:0.048590776459):0.0372829371381):0.00859075940423,(Esa@Thhalv10004228m:0.0378509854703,Aal@Aa_G102140_t1:0.0712272454125):1.00000050003e-06):0.00328120860999):0.0129090235079):0.0129090235079;"
p = "...?(?=@)|\(|\)"

result = re.findall(p, s)
```

and you have your result as a list, so you can make it string or do anything with it

for explaining what is happening :
`p` is regular expression pattern
so in this pattern:
`.` means matching any word
`...?(?=@)` means match any word until I get to a word `?` wich `?` is `@`, so this whole pattern means that you get any three words before `@`
`|` is `or` statement, I used it here to find another pattern
and the rest of them is to find `)` and `(`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing code can be hard to follow. [Tatsu](https://tatsu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) lets you write readable parsing code by combining grammars and python:

```
text = "(Esy@ESY15_g64743_DN3_SP7_c0:0.0726396855636,Aar@AA_maker7399_1:0.137507902808,((Spa@Tp2g18720:0.0318934795022,Cpl@CP2_g48793_DN3_SP8_c:0.0273465005242):9.05326020871e-05,(((Bst@Bostr_13083s0053_1:0.0332592496158,((Aly@AL8G21130_t1:0.0328569260951,Ath@AT5G48370_1:0.0391706378372):0.0205924636564,(Chi@CARHR183840_1:0.0954469923893,Cru@Carubv10026342m:0.0570981548016):0.00998579652059):0.0150356382287):0.0340484449097,(((Hco@scaff1034_g23864_DN3_SP8_c_TE35_CDS100:0.00823215335663,Hlo@DN13684_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0085462978729):0.0144626717872,Hla@DN22821_c0_g1_i1_p1:0.0225079453622):0.0206478928557,Hse@DN23412_c0_g1_i3_p1:0.048590776459):0.0372829371381):0.00859075940423,(Esa@Thhalv10004228m:0.0378509854703,Aal@Aa_G102140_t1:0.0712272454125):1.00000050003e-06):0.00328120860999):0.0129090235079):0.0129090235079;"

import sys
import tatsu

grammar = """
start = things ';'
    ;

things = thing [ ',' things ]
    ;

thing = x '@' y ':' number
    | '(' things ')' ':' number
    ;

x = /\w+/
    ;

y = /\w+/
    ;

number = /[+-]?\d+\.?\d*(e?[+-]?\d*)/
    ;
"""

class Semantics:
    def x(self, ast):
        # the method name matches the rule name
        print('X =', ast)

parser = tatsu.compile(grammar, semantics=Semantics())
parser.parse(text)
```